# Problem with typesetting Persian, Greek, Hebrew

Tags: greek, preamble, hebrew, xepersian

So, I am trying to write the following sample text, and when I type `\begin{hebrew} נְשִימָה \end{hebrew}`, all the rest of text goes all wrong. The same issue arises with Greek word.

> "لفظ (anima anemos) در زبان لاتین، (Ψυχή) psyché یونانی، نَفْس در عربی
> و נְשִימָה در عبری همگی به معنای دَم (نَفَس) آمده اند.‌‌"

I know something is wrong with preamble but I cannot point it out precisely. Here is the preamble, any helps would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{libertine}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}

\setmainlanguage{persian}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Arial}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\csname@twosidetrue\endcsname
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage[alwaysadjust]{paralist}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={170mm,257mm},
    left=22mm,
    top=22mm,
}
\usepackage{graphicx}%To insert images.
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}%To cross-reference accross the text.
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=RubineRed,urlcolor=Maroon,citecolor=ForestGreen}%Determines the color of the hyperlink and urlcolorlink.

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\newcommand\marginlabel[1]{\mbox{}\marginpar
    {\raggedright\hspace{0pt}#1}}

\usepackage[xindy,acronym,nonumberlist=true]{glossaries}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{xepersian}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2} 
\settextfont{XB Zar}
\defpersianfont\nast{X Davat}
\title{\nast{\Huge{}}}
\author{\nast{\huge{}}}
\date{\nast{}}

\begin{document}
    لفظ (\lr{anima anemos}) در زبان لاتین، (\begin{greek}Ψυχή\end{greek}) \lr{psyché} یونانی، نَفْس در عربی و \begin{hebrew}נְשִימָה\end{hebrew} در عبری همگی به معنای دَم (نَفَس) آمده اند. 
    \begin{hebrew}נְשִימָה\end{hebrew}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Tex.SX, your MWE is missing the `\begin{document}` and body of sample text

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes, I am aware of that as well, but as I have already mentioned, this is the preamble and by definition, preamble is write up to \begin{document}. Just adding the quoted text between \begin{document} and \end{document} would suffice to produce the document.

Comment: We need the MWE so we can compile the file on our end, recreate the problem, then solve it. In your case, after adding the missing body of the document, there still are many many errors. Some because you're loading packages that should be before polyglossia after loading it, some because of other reasons. Does your file successfully compile at all?

Comment: IMHO, the best way is to enter in the preamble the minimum that is requires to typeset the three languages, look if that works, and then gradually enter the rest and see where it fails.

Comment: Pieter, that would be a good place to start, but to answer the question we need more information. There is more than one problem that I can see currently just with the preamble. It does not compile. Other than that, is OP on a windows machine that has Ariel font? Does OP have Ariel font and does it support greek and hebrew? OP did not define greek as another language (in `\setotherlanguages`). How does OP typeset the languages? is he using `\texthebrew{}` for the Hebrew word? Some other way? We cannot answer without knowing these and that is what a MWE is for.

Comment: Yes the font is defined on a windows machine and it displays Greek font in Microsoft Word. As to the rest of your question, I don't know what are "OP" and "MWE". Please add to your kindness and clarify them for me

Comment: I removed the amsmath package and all its related commands as is stated in edit explanation and the file compiled and showed the Hebrew word, but not the Greek one.

Comment: Sorry, mali, OP is Original Poster (you :)  ), and MWE is Minimal Working Example. An example starting with `\documentclass{` and ending in `\end{document}` that we can test and fix

Comment: Ah. I see the problem now, \begin{heberw} should be used on a paragraph in which hebrew is the main font, it cannot be used in the middle of a paragraph that is written in another language. Try using the command `\texthebrew{נשימה}` (same with the greek one). When using the `\texthebrew` command you don't need the `\lr` commands.

Comment: Also, you should move `\usepackage{polyglossia}` and all related commands to after the `\makeindex`

Comment: Thank a lot. Now the only error displayed by TeXstudio is that "Undefined control sequence. ^^I\textgreek".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have cleaned up your Example to make it minimal, and I have fixed everything so that it would compile correctly. Here is the right way to go about with `polyglossia` and `xepersian` with XeLaTeX:

1. Load all packages (such as geometry and color) BEFORE the packages that use bidi.
2. Define all other languages you are using, this includes English and Greek (in `\setotherlanguages{hebrew, greek,english}`.
3. For languages requiring font, define the font.
4. Use `\textotherlanguage` (e.g. `\textgreek`) to write in other language mid-paragraph

Fixed MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{persian}
\setotherlanguages{hebrew,greek,english}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Frank Ruehl CLM}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}


\usepackage{xepersian}


\settextfont{XB Niloofar}
\defpersianfont\nast{X Davat}

\begin{document}
لفظ \textenglish{(anima anemos)} در زبان لاتین،(\textgreek{Ψυχή}) \textenglish{psyché} یونانی، نَفْس در عربی و \texthebrew{נְשִימָה} در عبری همگی به معنای دَم (نَفَس) آمده اند.
\end{document}
```

The fonts I used are the ones provided in TeXLive, but if you're on a windows machine and use Ariel that would work just as well.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version that works in LuaLaTeX, without explicit language tagging. (You do have to finesse whether opening and closing punctuation is left-to-right or right-to-left.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=sectioning.tabular, nil]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage[alwaysadjust]{paralist}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={170mm,257mm},
    left=22mm,
    top=22mm,
}
\usepackage{graphicx}%To insert images.
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}%To cross-reference accross the text.
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=RubineRed,urlcolor=Maroon,citecolor=ForestGreen}%Determines the color of the hyperlink and urlcolorlink.

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\newcommand\marginlabel[1]{\mbox{}\marginpar
    {\raggedright\hspace{0pt}#1}}

\usepackage[xindy,acronym,nonumberlist=true]{glossaries}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\babelprovide[import=fa, main, onchar=ids fonts]{persian}
\babelprovide[import=he, onchar=ids fonts]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import=el-polyton, onchar=ids fonts]{greek}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX }

% XB Zar is available at: https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/xb-zar
% To get italics that slant right-to-left, change the Italic faces to Oblique.
% As LuaTeX has trouble parsing filenames with spaces, I load this family by
% its PostScript names.
\defaultfontfeatures[XBZar]{
  BoldFont={*-Bold},
  ItalicFont={*-Italic},
  BoldItalicFont={*-BoldItalic}}

\defaultfontfeatures[LibertinusSerif]{
  Ligatures=Common}

\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale=1.0]{Libertinus Serif}
\babelfont[persian]{rm}
          {XB Zar}
%\babelfont{sf}
%          {Arial}

\begin{document}"لفظ (anima anemos) در زبان لاتین، (Ψυχή~(psyché یونانی، نَفْس در عربی و נְשִימָה در عبری همگی به معنای دَم (نَفَس) آمده اند``
\end{document}
```

[image: XB Zar/Libertinus sample]

You can additionally set `\babelfont{tt}` and `\setmathfont` if you need them.  (Arabic Latin Modern Fixed is a good fixed-width Arabic font for TeX.  Khaled Hosny’s Libertinus Math is an OpenType math font that might work here, or STIX Two Math).

You probably do still want to use explicit language tagging instead of auto-detection if you’re including more than a few isolated words in a second language.  Here, for example, introducing a hyphenation point in `psy\-ché` to improve the excessive word spacing of the first line clashes with the bidirectional algorithm and gives incorrect output.

Answer (score 0):

There's a whole bunch of mess in the preamble. I could not get your code to compile thanks to some conflicts between packages. **Don't ignore errors**.

Also, `polyglossia` should provide the functionality that you need for Persian without loading `xepersian`. You also don't need

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

and `polyglossia` will load `fontspec`

I don't have Libertine installed, so I used this simplified preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{libertine}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{FreeSerif}

\setmainlanguage{persian}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{greek} % ❶
\setotherlanguage{latin} % ❷
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Arial}
```

I added the language definitions for Latin and Greek.

Then I had the document body of:

```
\begin{document}
    لفظ (\textlatin{anima anemos}) در زبان لاتین، (\begin{greek}Ψυχή\end{greek}) \textlatin{psyché} یونانی، نَفْس در عربی و \begin{hebrew}נְשִימָה\end{hebrew} در عبری همگی به معنای دَم (نَفَس) آمده اند. 
    \begin{hebrew}נְשִימָה\end{hebrew}
    \end{document}
```

(I used `\textlatin` instead of `\lr` since the latter is not defined by `polyglossia`). The output was:

[image]

Which with my small Latin, less Greek, vanishing Hebrew and absent Farsi appears to be the correct typesetting of your input.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but I need xepersian package for \defpersianfont command. Is there another way so that I can keep the xepersian package?

Comment: `\defpersianfont` is just defining a new font family with font spec specifying options of `Script=Persian,Ligatures=PersianTeX`. For your needs, you could just write `\newfontfamily\persianfont[Script=Persian,Ligatures=PersianTeX]{XB Zar}` and `\newfontfamily\nastfamily[Script=Persian,Ligatures=PersianTeX]{X Davat}` and then `\NewDocumentCommand{\nast}{m}{{\nastfamily #1}}`